# When do I use Present Continuous for near future instead of "be going to"?

Tags: differences, future, present-progressive

I am reading [this lesson](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html) about present continuous. 
As the writer states

> USE 3 **Near Future**
>   Sometimes, speakers use the Present Continuous to indicate that something will or will not happen in the near future.

Examples:

1. I am meeting some friends after work.
2. I am not going to the party tonight.
3. Is he visiting his parents next weekend?
4. Isn't he coming with us tonight? "

The lesson says:  ***Sometimes***, speakers use the Present Continuous...

My question is when are these "sometimes"?

Answer (score 9):

The present continuous used for the future implies *[planning and arrangement](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/)*:

> There is a suggestion that more than one person is aware of the event,
>   and that some preparation has already happened. e.g.
>
> edufind.com

*I'm meeting Joe at the station* > **implies** > Joe and I have arranged it.
*I am arriving tomorrow.* > **implies** > I have my ticket.
*We're having a staff meeting next Monday.* > **implies** > The staff knows about it.

Another instructor adds *[intention](http://www.learnenglishlanguagewell.com/grammar/present-continuous-for-future/)* as an implication, and wisely recommends mentioning the future time frame to avoid ambiguity:

> We use the present continuous tense to talk about the future when an
>   action or situation is part of a (*sic*):
>
> plan
>   an arrangement
>   intention.
>
> Mary’s studying in the library. (now)
>   She’s studying at Bethan’s house **this evening**. (future)
>
> Learnenglishlanguagewell.com

The notion of **near** future will be impacted by the intensity of the *intention*, *planning* and *arrangements*.

- We are meeting next week.
- He is graduating next May.
- I am retiring in six years!

Comment: @Adio Note that this is not restricted to the **near** future: "I'm graduating next year and going on to graduate school."

Comment: ... _Big Boy_ is returning to active service in 2019.

Comment: @Stone I wonder how *Winter is coming* fits into all this. :)

Comment: @tchrist Lhude sing goddam? ... Depends on context.